# I am no longer able to burn discs using my MacBook's SuperDrive. How can I fix it?

Tags: snow-leopard, optical-drive, dvd-burning

About a year ago, the SuperDrive in my 2010 MacBook appeared to stop working. When I insert a blank CD or DVD, the disc does not show up in the Finder. The drive appears in Disk Utility, and I am able to eject it from there. I assumed this was a hardware problem with the SuperDrive, so I just purchased an external Samsung USB DVD drive. I am seeing the exact same behavior with it. **This leads me to believe there is some kind of OS X problem rather than it stemming from the drives.**

What steps should I take to troubleshoot and try to fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I [reset the SMC](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT3964?viewlocale=en_US) and the SuperDrive is working again.